# How can I change the color of one button and reset color of previous that I clicked before, so only one at the same time could have color

Tags: flutter, dart

I just can't find any methods, can you give me hint or maybe your opinion
[image: flutter]

Comment: Can you post your current code?

Comment: Providing code would help us understand your problem better

Answer (score 0):

I do this for this part:

1. create a list of type int with same number of element as the number of button for example we have 4 buttons then we can declare a list like this

```
List<int> b = [0,0,0,0];
```

after this in the onPressed function we can do this:

```
setState({
b[0]==0?b[0]=1:b[0]=0;
b[1]=0;
b[2]=0;
b[3]=0;
)};
```

and for color in color section of button do this:

```
color: b[0]==0?Colors.white:Colors.black;
```

do the same for every button.

You can check this code for more reference:

```
Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: [
              FlatButton(
                color: to[0]==0?primaryColor:null,
                onPressed: (){
                  setState(() {
                    to[0]==0?to[0]=1:to[0]=0;
                    to[1]=0;
                    to[2]=0;
                    to[3]=0;
                  });
                },
                  child: Text("All")
              ),
              FlatButton(
                  color: to[1]==0?primaryColor:null,
                  onPressed: (){
                    setState(() {
                      to[1]==0?t="Company":t="All";
                      to[1]==0?to[1]=1:to[1]=0;
                      to[0]=0;
                      to[2]=0;
                      to[3]=0;
                    });
                  },
                  child: Text("Company")
              ),
              FlatButton(
                  color: to[2]==0?primaryColor:null,
                  onPressed: (){
                    setState(() {
                      to[2]==0?t="Driver":t="All";
                      to[2]==0?to[2]=1:to[2]=0;
                      to[0]=0;
                      to[1]=0;
                      to[3]=0;
                    });
                  },
                  child: Text("Drivers")
              ),
              FlatButton(
                  color: to[3]==0?primaryColor:null,
                  onPressed: (){
                    setState(() {
                      to[3]==0?t="Users":t="All";
                      to[3]==0?to[3]=1:to[3]=0;
                      to[0]=0;
                      to[1]=0;
                      to[2]=0;
                    });
                  },
                  child: Text("Users")
              )
            ],
          ),
```

Comment: 10q, but what if I have dynamic amount of buttons?

Comment: for every generated button add an element to the list

Answer (score 0):

MAKE THREE VARIBLES NUMBERS WHICH MUST BE DIFFERNET :

```
white_color = Colors.white
black_color = Colors.black

button_no_1 =1 
button_no_2 = 2
button_no_3 = 3

color = 1
```

```
Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: [
              FlatButton(
                color: (color==button_no_1)?black_color:white_color
                onPressed: (){
                  setState(() {
                    color = button_no_1
                  });
                },
                  child: Text("first button")
              ),
```

AND IT WORKS FINE ,

Comment: thank you, but I could have a lot of buttons, cuz it took the amount from the list.

Comment: tryna make a list of button numbers for the numbers of button !